Can't understand how to stop this specific IP or source of message in journalctl
below is an excerpt from my Journal. I can't figure out what is causing it. I've blocked that IP implicitly in UFW so I guess it's internal. No clue where to go from here.
Jul 11 14:45:04 abysslocal sshd[1611420]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Jul 11 14:45:04 abysslocal sshd[1611420]: Connection closed by 180.214.239.93 port 51175
Jul 11 14:45:08 abysslocal sshd[1611421]: Unable to negotiate with 180.214.239.93 port 51286: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Jul 11 14:45:19 abysslocal sshd[1611471]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Jul 11 14:45:19 abysslocal sshd[1611471]: Connection closed by 180.214.239.93 port 51602


Please edit your question to add the exact firewall rule that should be denying this, and the interfaces of this host with addresses.
